# Stream Reader not reading punctuation correctly

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a created a C# WCF web service which accepts a Stream input as the body of the request is being passed in x-www-form-urlencoded. When I receive my request I use the following to read the contents of the stream:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseInput(Stream input)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> ReturnedData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                string strInput = new StreamReader(input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
                string[] inputs = strInput.Split('&');

                foreach (var item in inputs)
                {
                    string[] keyValue = item.Split('=');

                    ReturnedData.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Tracing.IAConnectorTopic.exception(new Exception($"Error parsing input body: {ex.Message}"));
            }
 


            return ReturnedData;
        }
```

The issue I am finding is if the input is like the following:

Input=This is test data + more data!

the StreamReader will return:

Input=This%20is%20test%20data%20%2B%20more%20data%21

How can I stop the stream reader converting the space and '+' or any other special characters.

I have already tried changing the Encoding type put it does not work.

Comment: MAybe read bytes from stream and parse them to characters? Or verify how data is send - maybe there special characters get replaced... %20 is common replacement for space, for example in links you type in the browser :) Just try: https://www.google.com/search?q=look%20space   Note `look%20space` - you will see that %20 is replaced with space in text box on google results page

Comment: It seems you are dissecting a URL, or?. Have a look at [UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode).

Comment: UrlDecode is what I needed thank you

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved. Can you share your solution to help people with similar problems?